# How to bind oData model to table in block view of object page layout?

Tags: javascript, xml, odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

How do i bind the model data from the oData entityset response to the table inside the xml block view? 
I want to set/bind the model data to table rows in the view 'directly' instead of binding it to table rows in the object page view controller methods via events

```
   Below code from block view:

    <Table id="sponClassTable" growing="true" growingThreshold="5"
inset="false"
    items="{
        path: '/SponClassSet'
    }">

   Binding to table cells in block view:

            <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text 
                    text="{sponsModel>SponsoredClass}"/>
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>ClassType}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>IdcRelevant}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SponsClassDesc}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SpClFromDt}" />       
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SpClDefault}" />                      

            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding your table to different models.

The table items are bound to an unnamed model  path: '/SponClassSet' and your Text cells are bound to a named model called  sponsModel text="{sponsModel>SponsoredClass} ?
What name are you using for your odata model ? Unnamend or sponsModel ? Search for method setModel in your code or take a look in your manifest.json which name you have chosen for  your Odata model.
In addition to that take a look in the OpenUi5 documentation how views are bind to data models.

```
<Table id="sponClassTable" growing="true" growingThreshold="5"
inset="false"
    items="{
        path: '/SponClassSet'
    }">

   Same sub-view, here Binding to table rows:
            <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text 
                    text="{sponsModel>SponsoredClass}"/>
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>ClassType}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>IdcRelevant}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SponsClassDesc}" />
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SpClFromDt}" />       
                <Text
                    text="{sponsModel>SpClDefault}" />                      

            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Comment: Hi Franceso, thank you for the tip! I was giving wrong path for my entityset records that were coming from named model in items path. I was giving the path to 'entityset' instead of path to named model for items property in table tag.Now i changed path to: items="{path: 'sponsModel>/results'}" inside the table tag in xml block view and i am able to populate the data/records successfully in the table